# Cannot fetching data with php in Linux

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect to a database and fetch data , But I can't do that . Would you mind helping me what is the problem ? By the way I use Linux Ubuntu. Here is the code and info  :

```
<?php

// DB name : db
// Table name : users
// Columns : username , password
mysql_connect("localhost" "root" "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo "Username :".$fetch['username'];
echo "Password :".$fetch['password'];
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error?

Comment: give a comma in first line. always use [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_method) method to find the error.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to separate the variables on your `mysql_connect` statement. Do like this

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
                   ------^  -----^   // Added commas here
```

Do it like this:

```
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Username :".$fetch['username'];
    echo "Password :".$fetch['password'];
}
```

Migrating to `MySQLi` from `mysql_*`, read [`here`](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi)

---

Most importantly, stop using **`mysql_*`** functions as they are deprecated. Switch to **`MySQLi`** or **`PDO`**.

Comment: Thank you , but still I cannot fetch data . Here is the result           Username :Password :

Comment: How to stop using mysql_* ? I did'nt got it.

Comment: sorry What is the MYSQL_ASSOC‌ ?

Comment: It is the result type. Read about that here http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#refsect1-function.mysql-fetch-array-returnvalues

Comment: Oh , I forgot to give some value to columns , How can I do that by terminal ?